# Can we suspense an images using react-query?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

For example:

```js
const { data } = useQuery({
  queryKey: 'src',
  queryFn: async() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const image = new Image();
      image.src = src;
      image.onload = () => resolve(src);
      image.onerror = reject;
    })
  }
})
```

And once the image loads successfully, we can show the img tag with the data containing the src, or this is a bad idea and there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: why would you want to do that? the browser can cache images just fine ...

Comment: I apologize for the late response. My thought was as follows. Let's say I have a post with an image and content for the post. In most cases, or at least that's how I've noticed. The content for the post loads and shows up faster than the image, especially with a slow internet connection. My question is how can I suspence the whole post to be displayed before the image is loaded. And since I use react-query in my project I thought about whether this is possible or my approach is wrong and there's a better way to do that.